# How to purge Java artifacts spread over many branches and commits from a GitHub repo?

Tags: git, github

Way back in the past I accidentally committed a large number of Java artifacts (.war, .jar and .class) into my GitHub repo. This resulted in a huge bloat in size to about 100Mb. I didn't notice until many commits and branch merges later.

Fortunately, there is a lot of info out there about this and so after trawling endlessly through StackOverflow, GitHub and Git documentation (thanks everyone!) I finally managed to put the following script together:

```
#!/bin/bash          
echo "Removing history for *.war, *.jar, *.class files"

echo "Starting size"
git count-objects -v

echo "Removing history for *.war, *.jar, *.class files"
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.war' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.jar' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.class' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

echo "Purging refs and garbage collection"
# Purge the backups 
rm -Rf .git/refs/original

# Force reflog to expire now (not in the default 30 days)
git reflog expire --expire=now --all

# Prune
git gc --prune=now

# Aggressive garbage collection
git gc --aggressive --prune=now

echo 
echo "Ending size (size-pack shows new size in Kb)"
git count-objects -v

# Can't do this in the script - it needs a human to be sure
echo
echo "Now use this command to force the changes into your remote repo (origin)"
echo 
echo git push --all origin --force
```

This worked perfectly locally, my 100Mb repo dropped to about 2Mb. I then used the

```
git push --all origin --force
```

command to overwrite all branches in the GitHub repo with my local changes. All went well. To check everything I deleted my local repo and cloned from GitHub. This should have been 2Mb, but was again 100Mb.

So, after all that rambling, where have I gone wrong? How can I force GitHub to use my local repo with its purged history?

**Edits for further information**

The GitHub repo can't be deleted since it has a lot of additional information surrounding it (issues, wiki, watches etc). Performing this script against an empty scratch repo works fine - the cloned repo is 2Mb.

The problem remains as to why it doesn't work with the main repo.

Comment: Since you're force pushing anyway, is it an option to start a new repo? (You'd lose all the issues, of course.) You can check whether it would be smaller by pushing the cleaned up version to a scratch repo on GitHub.

Comment: There is a large amount of information surrounding the current repo (issues, wiki, watches, collaborators etc) so I'd prefer to avoid deleting it and starting again.

Comment: I understand. Still, it would be interesting to see whether a scratch repo pushed from the cleaned-up version is actually smaller, otherwise you've probably made a mistake when measuring the local size.

Comment: Good advice - I'll put together a scratch repo just to try it out and report back.

Comment: OK - it all worked fine with the scratch repo. The clone was 2Mb as expected and all branches work.

Comment: Now how to make it work for the main repo?

Comment: Are the bloat commits accessible from a tag in the old repository?  If you run `git fsck` on a new clone of the repository what do you get?

Comment: @AndrewMyers The fsck on the scratch has 6709 objects (2Mb) and against a clone of the original repo has 7479 (100Mb) making me think that the push has failed to overwrite it.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like the original commits are still accessible somehow.  Do you have any tags in the repository?  I don't think the `--all` will overwrite tags, just branches.

Comment: @AndrewMyers Using git tag reveals no tags. Is there any other way to force branches to be overwritten?

Comment: @GaryRowe `git push -f` is how I would do it, I guess you could delete remote branches and then recreate them.  Something else to check, `git push --all -f` will only overwrite the remote branches which you have a local copy of.  Is there a branch in the repository that didn't get overwritten because you had no local copy of it?

Comment: Very doubtful, this local repo was originally taken as a clone of the origin, then cleaned and force pushed back. It should have all the branches.

Comment: @GaryRowe hmm, I'm running out of ideas then.  You could try running `gitk --all` in the repository.  If there's anything that's still referencing the old commits it should show up there.

Comment: @AndrewMyers Well it took a detailed support analysis from GitHub to get to the bottom of this - it was all because of a fork. Details in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It was all because of a fork**

It turns out that if someone forks your repo on GitHub, then they retain links and references to entries within it. Consequently, your purge won't work unless everyone who is holding a fork also runs the script on their repo.